# Spring Integration : Set payload.name before sending to a channel (Payload type is ByteArrayOutputStream)

Tags: spring-integration

I am marshalling a incoming message to XML(using JAXB) to ByteArrayOutputStream and sending to SFTP using out bound channel adapter.

```
outputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<ByteArrayOutputStream>(bos));
```

All works well, but the file name is named as "59262ea2-acda-e2be-770c-f4073390c191.msg"

I would like to save the file with a specific name based on the incoming message.

```
Incoming message is like : Message{name='myfilename'; field='abc'}

XML File : <MYMessage>  <name>myfilename</name> <MYMessage>
```

I used remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName() + '.xml'" to save the file extension as "xml" works well too.

using "remote-filename-generator", I need to do extra work to construct the file name.

Just worndering can I set payload name before sending to channel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear how are you going to get file name from the `ByteArrayOutputStream`...

However the `remote-filename-generator-expression` can get access to the `MessageHeaders`.

So, if you will be able to specify the file name as header, there will be just enough to have this:

```
remote-filename-generator-expression="headers[fileName] + '.xml'"
```

Comment: I was using 
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      marshaller.marshal(msg, baos);
      outputChannel.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>(baos.toByteArray()));
      
      Now with your suggestion, it works like charm. thanks.